# CMS for single user-editable pages?

Tags: cms

Does anybody know of a CMS where users can edit their own page, and their page *only* (something similar to about.me, except with more customization/options)? I'm not talking about profiles, but more like an individual web page for people's businesses. I want to be able to give local businesses the opportunity to make a single web page for their businesses with ease.

I have looked at many CMS's, but I can't find anything that offers this type of functionality. I've check out the following:

- Unify
- Concrete 5
- Drupal
- Simple CMS
- CMS Made Simple
  (and more)

If anybody knows a CMS with the functionality that I'm looking for, or even a regular CMS with modules/plugins that I would be able to use, that would be awesome.

Also: the cheaper, the better :D

Thanks,
Gerard

Comment: I think in CMSMS the user who has created a page can always edit it.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to use [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/). Give each user a page with only the most current post displayed.

Comment: Another hint on Wordpress: you may use the multiblog-feature to have a single site with multiple pages and posts per user;

Comment: I'd go with Wordpress too, there's lot's of plugins that will allow you to get exactly what you want. I've created several different websites using it and have yet to fail to find to what I need using plugins.