# Best CMS for single user editable pages?

Tags: cms, permissions

I've already found this older thread with the same quastion, but using Wordpress is not an option:

[CMS for single user-editable pages?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15700/cms-for-single-user-editable-pages)

Does anybody knows a CMS or some other piece of software which allows a user to register and create/edit one single page? The user should only be able to manage it's own page, nothing else in the adminpanel should be visible.

Pages created by the users should be inactive until a moderator reviews and publish them in the normal site structure. Any suggustions?

At the moment I'm using couchcms but it has no ACL-feature at all.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why is Wordpress not an option? It could easily do what you want.

Comment: We are using Wordpress for 2 existing sites and I - personally - don't like Wordpress as a CMS because of the many configuration settings and needed plugins. But it is great as a the blogging software it was meant to be.

Comment: It's an opinion and you should go with the software you feel better with, however the many configurations available are the reason Wordpress is so modular and flexible.

Comment: I agree with you. And if I'm not satisfied with the drupal-solution, I'll have to rethink an give Wordpress a try.

Comment: Drupal is also great, give it a try and we will be here to help if you need.

Answer (score 1):

[Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/)'s built-in permission and publishing status system, along with rules can do this.

First, et up a rule that creates an empty page for a user upon registration.  Set the default permission for user to "edit own page", put not to create new pages. Also set default status for pages to be "unpublished" until published by a moderator.

For an introduction to Drupal rules and an editorial workflow, see: https://www.drupal.org/node/550716

Comment: Sounds exactly like what I'm looking for. I'll give it a try and report back later. Thanks for your answer :)